# Static_cast no matching function for call

Tags: c++, static-cast

Could you please explain work of static_cast?

Why this code doesn't work?

```
D another_d = static_cast<D>(br); // ERROR - no matching function for call to ‘D::D(B&)’
```

**My code**

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

struct B {
    int m = 0;
    void hello() const {
        std::cout << "Hello world, this is B!\n";
    }
};

struct D : B {
    void hello() const {
        std::cout << "Hello world, this is D!\n";
    }
};

int main(){
    D d;
    B br = d; // upcast via implicit conversion
    br.hello(); // Hello world, this is B!
    // D another_d = static_cast<D>(br); // ERROR - no matching function for call to ‘D::D(B&)’
    D& another_d = static_cast<D&>(br); // OK
    another_d.hello(); // Hello world, this is D!
}
```

Comment: FYI: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/7478597) (A simple `#include <iostream>` would have worked as well and makes your sample portable.) ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
B br = d; // upcast via implicit conversion
```

This is [object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/274626/7478597). `br` is an instance of `B` and copies only the `B` part of `d`. (This implies down-casting of `d` to `B&` which the compiler can do implicitly because `D` is derived from `B`.)

```
D another_d = static_cast<D>(br);
```

This is the attempt to create an instance of `D` from an instance of `B`.
While `D` is also a `B` (due to inheritance) the opposite is not true.
So, there is nothing the compiler can do implicitly.

To make this working, a constructor `D(B&)` has to be defined.

To illustrate this: `D` might have additional member variables which cannot copied from `B`, and this is what such constructor had to handle in any way.

```
D& another_d = static_cast<D&>(br); // OK
```

This is not really OK. It might (seem to) work as `D` doesn't contain additional member variables.

`br` is an instance of `B` (not of `D`). "Faking" a reference to `D` is actually a lie but doing this explicitly (in code) makes the compiler silent. However, it's still wrong.

Comment: thank you, after this answer it seems that static_cast is really useful for inductrial programming only for void* casting, isn't it?

Comment: @swor `static_cast` is the rescue in complex production code where clean programming sometimes cannot be achieved with reasonable effort. But, it has always to be used with caaare. ;-)

Comment: @swor Imagine, you have an instance of `D` but it is stored as pointer to `B` (`B*`) or reference to `B` (`B&`). And for any reason, you cannot change this detail. At some point, you get a pointer/reference to `B` but you know for sure that it actually addresses a `D`. The first approach should be to use `virtual` member functions but this is not the solution in any case (and comes with additional costs). In this case, a `static_cast<D*>`/`static_cast<D&>` might be the rescue. Maybe, another design would prevent this but might be too much effort for a specific issue.